# Issues with getting mysql to run on linux server

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble logging in to mysql from linux terminal.  I get this error:

```
Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
(using password: NO)
```

I have tried changing the user name and password to match that that I use to log into the server and still no use.

When I try something like this I get the following:

> gweirich@col-citwebdev:~> mysql show tables
>
> mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib
>   5.0.96, for suse-linux-gnu (i686) using  EditLine wrapper Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle 
>   and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]   -?, --help          Display this
>   help and exit.   -I, --help          Synonym for -?   --auto-rehash
>   Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with...

and I am assuming this is the important part that might help:

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf  The following groups are read: mysql client The
>   following options may be given as the first argument:
>   --print-defaults  Print the program argument list and exit
>   --no-defaults     Don't read default options from any options file
>   --defaults-file=# Only read default options from the given file #
>   --defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read
>
> Variables (--variable-name=value) and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE} 
>   Value (after reading options)
>   --------------------------------- ----------------------------- auto-rehash                       TRUE character-sets-dir
>   (No default value) default-character-set             latin1 comments
>   FALSE compress                          FALSE database
>   (No default value) delimiter                         ; vertical
>   FALSE force                             FALSE named-commands
>   FALSE ignore-spaces                     FALSE local-infile
>   FALSE no-beep                           FALSE host
>   (No default value) html                              FALSE xml
>   FALSE line-numbers                      TRUE unbuffered
>   FALSE column-names                      TRUE sigint-ignore
>   FALSE port                              0 prompt
>   mysql>  quick                             FALSE raw
>   FALSE reconnect                         TRUE socket
>   (No default value) ssl                               FALSE ssl-ca
>   (No default value) ssl-capath                        (No default
>   value) ssl-cert                          (No default value) ssl-cipher
>   (No default value) ssl-key                           (No default
>   value) ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE table
>   FALSE debug-info                        FALSE user
>   (No default value) safe-updates                      FALSE
>   i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE connect_timeout
>   0 max_allowed_packet                16777216 net_buffer_length
>   16384 select_limit                      1000 max_join_size
>   1000000 secure-auth                       FALSE show-warnings
>   FALSE

How do I login to mysql to run on the server?

Comment: The first code block indicates you are not using a password to log in. Are you typing `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: This is start to finish what I get if I enter what you suggest. Obviously I entered my password when prompted.
>Last login: Fri Feb 21 17:26:47 on ttys000

>George-Weirichs-MacBook-Pro:~ gaw951$ ssh gweirich@citwebdev.cscc.edu

>Password: 

>Last login: Fri Feb 21 17:28:30 2014 from 76.1.34.241

>gweirich@col-citwebdev:~> mysql -u root -p

>Enter password: 

>ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: YES)

>gweirich@col-citwebdev:~>

It is a server at the school and I assume I am blocked out?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need the beginner for beginners tutorial on mysql.  I'll hold your hand for a while.  But at some point you will have to learn to troubleshoot on your own, or you will never become a programmer.

**Get the kind of server you are on**

```
el@apollo:~$ uname -a
Linux apollo 3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:25:51 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**See if you have MySQL running:**

```
el@apollo:~$ service mysql status
mysql start/running, process 1264
```

**Restart it for great justice:**

```
el@apollo:/var/log$ sudo service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 24303
el@apollo:/var/log$
```

**Try to login with root if you know the password:**

```
el@apollo:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4042
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

And now you are logged in.  Exit out.

**See if mysql is a running process.**

```
el@apollo:/var/log$ ps -ef | grep mysql
el        1995  1993  0 Feb13 ?        00:02:57 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/home/el/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --datadir=/home/el/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --socket=/home/el/.local/share/akonadi/socket-apollo/mysql.socket
mysql    24303     1  0 23:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
el       24474 23836  0 23:24 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

**Then slow down and RTM**

```
man mysql
```

**Read the mysql config file**

```
el@apollo:/var/log$ locate my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Open that file and read it.  Don't just skim it.  Read it. If you don't understand something in there, google it.

**Read the getting started manual here for your MySQL version:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/batch-mode.html

**When you do everything right, you can do what I do.  Login**

```
el@apollo:/var/log$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
mysql>
```

**Get the version:**

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Query your databases if you have any**

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| your_db            |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
| test               |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Change to your database if you already have one**

```
mysql> use your_db
Database changed
mysql>
```

**Make a table, add rows, query it**

```
mysql> create table foo (id INT, moobar TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values (47, "You have to learn to do this for yourself gaw951");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id   | moobar                                           |
+------+--------------------------------------------------+
|   47 | You have to learn to do this for yourself gaw951 |
+------+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then do a google search online for these things: mysql procedure, trigger, function, use an API to interface your langage (java, python, C++, etc) to the database, load a file from disk to table, dump a table to disk.  Learn about indexes, optimizations and everything else you can find.  Don't skimp on any of these things, mastering all these is required and you will be using every bit of it in the real world.